# Penalized model based clustering variable selection with L1 penalty

Tags: feature-selection, regularization, expectation-maximization

Ok so I am working through a [paper](https://jmlr.org/papers/volume8/pan07a/pan07a.pdf) by Pan and Shen where they maximize a penalized version of the complete data log-likelihood
$$
Q_{P}\left(\Theta ; \Theta^{(m)}\right)=E_{\Theta^{(m)}}\left(\log L_{c, P} \mid X\right)=\sum_{k} \sum_{j} \tau_{k j}^{(m)}\left[\log \pi_{k}+\log f_{k}\left(x_{j} ; \theta_{k}\right)\right]-\lambda \sum_{k} \sum_{p}\left|\mu_{k p}\right|
$$

where
$$
f_{k}\left(x ; \theta_{k}\right)=\frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{P / 2}|V|} \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(x-\mu_{k}\right)^{\prime} V^{-1}\left(x-\mu_{k}\right)\right),
$$
and $V=\operatorname{diag}\left(\sigma_{1}, \sigma_{2}, \ldots, \sigma_{P}\right)$, and $|V|=\prod_{p=1}^{P} \sigma_{p} .$

using the EM- algorithm in order to perform variable selection on very high dimensional data.

k is the number of clusters, p is the number of variables and j is the number of observations.

For the life of me, I do not understand why this works. Like what is the intuition behind this? Is there some sort of graphical representation to explain this?

The goal is to estimate the set of parameters that will give us the maximum value for $Q_{P}\left(\Theta ; \Theta^{(m)}\right)$ right? I don't understand how subtracting $\lambda \sum_{k} \sum_{p}\left|\mu_{k p}\right|$ helps us.

Please help!

Comment: Do you understand how the Lasso penalty in regression works? If you do, it is much easier to explain, as this is not very different.

Comment: @ChristianHennig Yes, I understand it in the regression sense. Just finding it hard to form the picture in my head for this case.

Answer (score 0):

What the penalty does is favouring solutions that have small values of $|\mu_{kp}|$, i.e., $|\mu_{kp}|$ will be shrunken, and as with the lasso in regression there will be a tendency to set $|\mu_{kp}|=0$ precisely. Now the assumption here is that within-cluster variances are the same over clusters, and this means that if indeed $|\mu_{kp}|=0$ for a certain variable $p$ and all clusters $k$, the variable doesn't differ between clusters and doesn't contribute anything to the clustering, in which case the variable can be removed, and therefore variable selection happens. (As far as I understand, they don't specifically enforce in any way that for given $p$, $|\mu_{kp}|=0$ happens easily for *all* clusters, so this will only happen if clearly supported by the data.)

Shrinking the nonzero $|\mu_{kp}|$ is not necessarily helpful, but that discussion is similar to lasso. So overall this can be seen as just applying the lasso idea to model-based clustering (and the geometrical reason why it tends to set some means to zero should also be pretty much the same). A difficulty is that you can't select your $\lambda$ using standard cross-validation, as there are no labelled observations. They have a proposal for doing that but I'm skeptical.